# How to get Group position from onChildClick()?

Tags: android, position, expandablelistview

I have an `ExpandableListView` view and I've implemented `OnChildClickListener`, but I need to get the group of that child, more specifically - the text staying as a label of that group.

How can I do that?

1. Should I implement `OnGroupClickListener`?
2. Can somebody show me how to use `getPackedPositionGroup()` or any of the `getPacked<somethingf>()` methods to get to the text on the group element of expandable list view?

[Edit - addition]

the called is in Map class, which is something like this:

```
public class MapCommand extends Activity implements OnChildClickListener {
.....

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    firstStepSwitcher(v, childPosition);

            ///HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO FIND THE GROUP!!!

        return true;
    }
}
```

The view itself is in the layout XML.  I do not manage its display manually.

And it has separate class for adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did wrong was that I used to take the adapter for that ExpandableListView like this:

in (`public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)`)

```
parent.getAdapter();
```

But after looking into detail in the specification I found that I should take it like this:

```
ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter = parent.getExandableListAdapter();
```

from there on I do not have problem to get my group by calling:

```
String groupName = (String) mAdapter.getGroup(groupPosition);
```